# Concrete examples concerning standard deviations and mean absolute deviations

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

Is there a simple (or not simple?) algorithm that will churn out examples of *pairs* of moderately small finite multisets (hereinafter calls "sets") of moderately small integers satisfying the following desiderata, or at least the first several of them, for suitable values of "several"?

- The first set in the pair has a **larger standard deviation** and a **smaller mean absolute deviation from the mean** than the second;
- The SD and/or the MAD are, at least approximately, what I want them to be;
- The mean is an integer;
- The SD and/or the MAD is an integer;
- The are right-skewed or left-skewed or concentrated near the mean or approximately uniformly distributed according according to the user's choice.
- One can in other (specify) ways make them do one's bidding.